# Flutter - I want to create a custom TextFomrField border

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design, flutter-layout

This TextFormField should have different width in different borderside

For example:

- left border  = 3
- right border =1

How can I do that without using containers?

[the default code is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0RPL.png)

Comment: check `InputBorder` class - you can extend that class and provide any shape / border / fill pattern you want

Comment: ok thanks i will check this

Comment: it works i extends the OutlineInputBorder and override the paint function

Answer (score 1):

I just need to create a new class and extends the OutlineInputBorder and override the paint function and in canvas, i need to change to width of the line that i want with different width